# Web browser Automation Selecting a Link

Tags: html, vb.net, anchor

Is it possible to click on a random `<a>` from a loaded HTML document in embedded webBrowser in my form? I'm using VB.net

I'm in a spot of bother. I've managed to get the Webbrowser to navigate to the page I want to be on, now i want it to invoke with page elements.

This is where it gets odd ok, sorry.

I have a rich text box of urls (these URLS are user inputted and match the links on the page I've already navigated to.)

I'd like to select a url at random from the richtextbox (up holds up to 10 lines) then find  the `href=` on the page and invoke the `<a>`

Is this possible?

Comment: how about cleaning up the missing words from your post?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have the webBrowser control with the current page loaded, and you want to select from the textbox a link to navigate to.

So you have the WebBrowser.Document.Body.InnerHtml property where you have the HTML of the loaded document, so i guess you can search that to match the input from your text box and with the url from the href call the Navigate method.

Hope that helps

Comment: So i use WebBrowser.Document.Body.InnerHtml to find the links?

Comment: That's right, or if you need greater control there is always the html agility pack

Answer (score 0):

WebBrowser.Document doesn't provide good Intellisense, but you have the full range of dom functions available to you at this point... (eg. getElementsByTag(string); )